# I have a generating an APK error in release with DIO

Tags: flutter

I ´m currently developing an application which when consuming the services in debug, they work fine, but when making an APK in release, the DIO does not let consume the services.

this is my Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.cashpak.app">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_BIOMETRIC" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_FINGERPRINT" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_BIOMETRIC" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />

    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.location"
        android:required="false" />

    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.telephony"
        android:required="false" />

    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.wifi"
        android:required="false" />

    <application
        android:name="com.cashpak.app.CustomApp"
        android:allowBackup="false"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/allAppName"
        android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
        tools:ignore="DataExtractionRules"
        tools:targetApi="n">
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.cashpak.app.MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:exported="true"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">

            <!--
                 Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
                 the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
                 while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
                 to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI.
            -->
            <meta-data
                android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
                android:resource="@style/NormalTheme" />

            <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_channel_id"
                android:value="high_importance_channel" />

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <!--
 Don't delete the meta-data below.
             This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java
        -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

This is my Pubspec.yaml

```
name: cashpak_mobile
description: 
publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev

version: 1.0.0+2

environment:
  sdk: '>=2.18.6 <3.0.0'

data:
    path: data

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_native_splash: ^2.2.2
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.4
  connectivity_plus: ^2.3.0
  crypto: ^3.0.2
  encrypt: ^5.0.1
  logger: ^1.1.0
  dio: ^4.0.6
  json_annotation: ^4.7.0
  intl: ^0.18.0
  flutter_riverpod: ^1.0.4
  flutter_secure_storage: ^5.0.2
  shared_preferences: ^2.0.15
  firebase_crashlytics: ^3.3.4
  firebase_analytics: ^10.4.4
  firebase_core: ^2.15.0
  package_info: ^2.0.2
  launch_review: ^3.0.1
  flutter_localizations:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_svg: ^1.1.0
  flutter_html: ^3.0.0-alpha.5
  device_preview: ^1.1.0
  google_sign_in: ^5.4.0
  # firebase_auth: ^3.3.19
  step_progress_indicator: ^1.0.2
  share_plus: ^4.0.7
  screenshot: ^2.1.0
  path_provider: ^2.0.11
  package_info_plus: ^4.0.2
  pinput: ^2.2.31
  flutter_holo_date_picker: ^1.0.3
  device_info_plus: ^9.0.2
  auto_size_text: ^3.0.0
  url_launcher: ^6.1.5
  dart_ipify: ^1.1.1
  geolocator: ^9.0.1
  flutter_spinkit: ^5.1.0
  flutter_speed_dial: ^6.2.0
  flutter_countdown_timer: ^4.1.0
  timer_count_down: ^2.2.1
  local_auth: ^2.1.3
  permission_handler: ^10.2.0
  flutter_contacts: ^1.1.6
  webview_flutter: ^4.0.7
  qr_flutter: ^4.0.0
  firebase_messaging: ^14.6.5
  flutter_local_notifications: ^14.1.1
  fluttertoast: ^8.2.2
  flutter_scripts: ^0.0.3

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

  flutter_lints: ^2.0.1
  retrofit_generator: ^4.2.0
  build_runner: ^2.4.6

flutter:
  uses-material-design: true

  assets:
    - assets/images/
    - assets/dummy/
  
  fonts:
    - family: SourceSansPro
      fonts:
        - asset: assets/fonts/SourceSansPro-Regular.ttf
        - asset: assets/fonts/SourceSansPro-Bold.ttf
          weight: 700

flutter_intl:
  main_locale: es
  enabled: true

flutter_native_splash:
  image: 'assets/splash_content.png'
  color: '#185CE5'
  image_dark: 'assets/splash_content.png'
  color_dark: '#185CE5'

scripts:
  build_runner: flutter pub run build_runner build
```

I've tried with and without obfuscating the code, I've added and removed permissions from the manifest, but not.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using an HTTP address, make sure you have added `usesCleartextTraffic=true` inside the application tag in your AndroidManifest.xml. This will ensure even if your API endpoint is not secure, you will still be able to call the API.

```
<application
    android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
```

Comment: But if you see, in my manifest, I have this: <network-security-config>
    <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">

Comment: Oh, I didn't notice that part. Without more information, it's hard to understand the issue, but you can take a look at [this](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/59427#issuecomment-690003323) link as it may solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but it doesn't work.